# Android app + web service

Tags: c#, android, ios, wcf, xamarin

I'm new in Mobile dev. Going to use C#. I'm going to write small android(maybe iOs in the future) app. And I can't figure out what I need to use as web server. I want mobile client to send requests to server and get result from it. Best idea I have - use WCF web service and json.

- Is it a good idea?
- What can I use except WCF?
- What could I read about web servers for mobile application?

P.S. Link for some tutorial will be great.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this and why, but neutralized it.

Comment: REST service with JSON format data exchange is preferable. this might be helpful to you : http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/06/requesting-rest-webservice-with-json-in.html

Answer (score 1):

There are tonnes of tutorials out there on this topic.

I would use socket connections

For C# you can create a TCP Listener using sockets 
using System.Net.Sockets;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx

and like wise for the android 
TCP sockets would be an easy implementation.
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

As for Android and connectivity.
the Android developer platform is always a good start.
developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html

Or you could create a Rest interface in c# 
codeproject.com/Articles/112470/Developing-a-REST-Web-Service-using-C-A-walkthroug

and make a http call in android. depends on your intended application to what will be better for you

Answer (score 0):

Why REST + JSON is preferred over SOAP for mobile web services

http://www.bamboorocketapps.com/rest-json-vs-soap-xml/